Find all polynomials in $\mathbb{P_n}$ such that the Fixed point iteration converges for all initial guesses

Determine all polynomial fixed point functions, $ p \in  \mathbb{P_n}$ for some $n \geq 0$, that
satisfy: Fixed point iterations on $p$ will always converge to some fixed point for any initial guess.

Attempt: Suppose $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+ \ldots +a_nx^n$. Then first of all we need $p$ to have a fixed point. Therefore, $p(x)=x$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$. I am not sure if this gives enough estimates on the coefficients $a_i$.
To get convergence for all initial guesses $x_0$, we can impose that $p$ is a contractive map. Thus, we require
$$|p(x)-p(y)|=|\sum_{i=1}^na_i(x^i-y^i)|< |x-y|$$
One obvious solution is $a_i=0 $ for $i \geq 2$ and $|a_1|<1$. Are there any non-trivial solutions as well and how can I find them?

You can easily exclude all polynomials of degree $n \ge 2$.

@MartinR That was my guess too, but how do I show that? Thank you for the insight

If $\deg(f) \ge 2$ then $p(x)/x \to \infty$ for $n \to \infty$, so that $|p(x)| \ge 2 |x|$ for all sufficiently large $x$. It follows that the fixed point iteration does not converge for all initial values.
If $f(x) = a+bx$ with $b \ne 1$ then
$$
 f(x) - \frac{a}{1-b} = b \left( x - \frac{a}{1-b}\right)
$$
so that the fixed point iteration converges for all initial values if and only if $|b| < 1$, i.e. if $\deg(f) \le 1$ and $f$ is a contraction. (This includes the case of constant polynomials.)
That leaves us with the cases $f(x) = x$ and $f(x) = a+x$ with $a \ne 0$, which are easy.
